# Exception thrown on AWSSDK.SecurityToken

Tags: c#, aws-sdk

```
var roleArnToAssume = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/xxx-xxx";
var clientArn = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient();
var assumeRoleReq = new AssumeRoleRequest();
assumeRoleReq.DurationSeconds = 3600;
assumeRoleReq.RoleSessionName = "XXXXX";
assumeRoleReq.RoleArn = roleArnToAssume;
assumeRoleReq.ExternalId = "xxxxxXxxXxxxXXXXXXxxxxxx";
var assumeRoleRes = GetAssumeRoleResponseAsync(client: clientArn, request: assumeRoleReq);
string tempAccessKeyId = assumeRoleRes.Result.Credentials.AccessKeyId;
```

### At this point I get object null exception, but previously in line #2 I can see all the following exceptions in the output. This in the server (windows 2012 R2) in development machines is working fine (Windows 10).

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in AWSSDK.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Amazon.Runtime.AmazonClientException' in AWSSDK.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in AWSSDK.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in AWSSDK.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in AWSSDK.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in AWSSDK.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
```

It seems related to this:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1131

I already updated dlls.
AWSSDK.Core version used: 3.3.31.19
AWSSDK.SecurityToken : 3.3.4.58 & 3.3.100

Update 1:
I went to Debug/Windows/Exceptions Settings and clicked all the types of exceptions I'm getting. Now I have more info.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The app.config/web.config files for the application did not contain credential information'
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up changing my code completely:

```
var roleArnToAssume = "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/xxx-xxxx";
var assumeRoleReq = new AssumeRoleRequest();
assumeRoleReq.DurationSeconds = 3600;
assumeRoleReq.RoleSessionName = "XXXX";
assumeRoleReq.RoleArn = roleArnToAssume;
assumeRoleReq.ExternalId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

var endpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest1;
var e = endpoint.GetEndpointForService("S3"); 

Amazon.Runtime.AWSCredentials credentials =
                new Amazon.Runtime.BasicAWSCredentials("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

var clientArn = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(credentials);
var assumeRoleRes = GetAssumeRoleResponseAsync(client: clientArn, request: assumeRoleReq);

string tempAccessKeyId = assumeRoleRes.Result.Credentials.AccessKeyId;
```